# Running iPhone apps on ipad in full resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-interface, resolution

I developed an iPhone Portrait application compatible with 4S to 6+. I don't want to create a separate application for iPad device, instead it needs to run as iPhone application. By default iPad device takes **4S resolution** for running the application.

My Question:

> 1. Is there any possibilities to tell iPad device to run in 6+ resolution mode?
> 2. I used iPhone 5C and iPad Mini for testing
> 3. My application is developed with compact width and regular height mode Auto Layout.

Need your valuable answers !!!!

Answer (score 0):

To run an application on iPad at other than iPhone 4 resolution you need to deploy it as a universal app - it will then run at iPad resolution (1024x768 - @2x on retina devices)

Comment: thank u @Paulw11 .. For my first project I developed app compatible only with iPhone 5..When i ran the same in iPad it looked exactly same as 5 instead of 4S resolution...Same way if I want to develop my app compatible with 6+ what should I do to make it work on iPad ?

Comment: You can't make an app for iPhone 5 only.  An iPhone targeted app will run on all devices supported by the operating system - For ios8 this is 4S and above.  iPhone apps always run on iPad at 4S resolution (or 2x 4S resolution if you tap the little button).  The only way to get any different behaviour is to develop a universal app

Comment: ok actually I mean it for UI Design compatibility. I designed and developed all screen with 4 inch screen size and maked it compatible for below size screens

Comment: Ok.  That doesn't change the answer.  To get any other size on iPad you need to design your UI to work on an iPad screen and make your app Universal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application on iPad then make it universal App. Your application is iPhone app that's why its not able to detect iPad width & height and load default iPhone 4s width & Height.

You may try to learn how [Universal storyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM) work with Xcode 6.

Comment: thanks @santu .. I know it will not run with iPad resolution.. I want to change that loading concept on iPad which means need to run with 6+ res!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No Tommy, there is no way for a developer to allow their users to run "6+ resolution mode" on an iPad without also having the users to go through jailbreaking and difficult tweaking process. You can file a request on Apple's developer forum but it will be ignored because Apple just want you to do things their way - which is to build the f*cking universal app, pal. It's their philosophy.